# iOS - What programming language does Parse use?

Tags: javascript, php, ios, parse-platform

I've heard of Parse recently and how it's a good service to use for building a back end for an iOS app, but I can't find ANYWHERE that states what programming language I'll need to write that backend code...PHP? Javascript? Java? Which is it?

All I'm reading about are iOS sdk's, Javascript sdk's, etc. I just want to know what programming language I need to know in order to write backend code with Parse.

Comment: PHP is available: https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide

Comment: Wait so I choose between multiple languages to write backend code for my iOS app?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. Check their documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your parse client code in Swift or Objective-C but If you would need to write cloud code then you can write code in javaScript.

Here is a simple tutorial that describe the complete scenario how to startup a totally parse.com backend.

1-http://www.raywenderlich.com/98831/parse-tutorial-getting-started-web-backends

2-http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-app-backend-parse/

Hope it will help you to create wonderfull apps.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'll start reading up on all that!